# What type is expected for (elems: (A, B)*) in GenMapFactory

Tags: scala

The GenMapFactory class has an `apply` function, with the following signature

```
 def apply[A, B](elems: (A, B)*): CC[A, B] = (newBuilder[A, B] ++= elems).result()
```

What  kind of collection I'm supposed to use here ? I thought I could just use a sequence but that does not seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The * indicates a variable length argument list (also known as varargs).

In the case of a Map you would use it like this:

```
val newMap: Map[A, B] = Map((a0, b0), (a1, b1), (a2, b2))
```

There is also a neater way to express the (key, value) syntax, like this:

```
val newMap: Map[A, B] = Map(a0 -> b0, a1 -> b1, a2 -> b2)
```

Answer (score 2):

`(A, B)*` allows you to pass 0 or more `Tuple2[A, B]`s as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a sequence, you can:

```
val seq: Seq[(Int, Int)] = Seq(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4) // just an example
Map(seq: _*)
```